# "Persistence provider caller does not implement the EJB3 spec correctly." warning when deploying on JBoss 5.1.0.GA

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jboss, persistence

i get this hibernate warning pretty much every time i deploy a persistence unit on JBoss. its never the cause of any issues, but i was wondering if anyone knows what exactly this means, and can it be fixed/slicenced/worked-around in some way.

Comment: no, persistence.xml only (and annotations)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this comment](http://community.jboss.org/message/561482#561482) from Jaikiran Pai (RedHat employee member of the JBoss EJB3 development team):

> > Daniel Winz wrote:
> >
> > There is a warning that may stick together with the error:
> >
> > ```
> > 2010-09-12 12:10:52,759 WARN  [org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration] (HDScanner) Persistence provider caller does not implements the EJB3 spec correctly. PersistenceUnitInfo.getNewTempClassLoader() is null.
> > ```
>
> **You can ignore that log message**.

That's the best answer I've found so far about the warning (which is reported in [EJBTHREE-710](https://jira.jboss.org/browse/EJBTHREE-710) without any particular comment...).

Answer (score 0):

Check that you datasource is correctly and validate credential! I had same problem and I solved this way.